# How to include libraries through the python local server

Tags: python, d3.js, local

I'm currently running an html and jsp file locally and hosting it by running this command through the terminal: python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8888 &.

This has been going smoothly, but I recently ran into an issue where I have to include library files (d3, jQuery, ajax, etc.)

I've included the following command in my html file `<script src="../libs/d3.v3.min.js">` 
but noticed that it was pulling up a 404 error.  I've tried to remedy it with a change in script to : `<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js">`.

But I actually feel that it doesn't go to the root of the problem.  Why am I unable to include the files I have in my lib?

*Edited wording to question thanks for the heads up Amber:*  The lib file is located one directory up from the html file.

Comment: If the lib folder is in the same directory (rather than the one above), why are you prefixing the path with `../`?

Comment: Hey Amber, sorry I should clarify.  The folder structure is folder1 (includes both lib and folder 2)  folder 2 contains this html file so it should be the right structure

Comment: Have you checked in the console the path of the file that cannot be loaded?

Answer (score 1):

The `SimpleHTTPServer` module will only serve things that are within the directory you're telling it to serve and folders *beneath* that directory, for security reasons. (Otherwise a visitor could ask it for e.g. `../../../../etc/passwd` or similar.)

If you want to serve scripts and other assets, you'll need to put them in a subfolder of the directory you're running SimpleHTTPServer in.